# GLException: Profile GL4bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice

Tags: java, hardware, opengl

Recent update to LM 20 (Mate) (based on Ubuntu 20.04). A Java application I use has begun to get borked - window is tearing and ghosting, menus only becoming visible if I mouse over them, etc. Basically, unusable in its current state, although some of its functionality work still. It is #LancsBox, a corpus linguistics tool suite, and up until recently very stable and reliable. But the update appears to have messed it up somehow. It does require Oracle java 8.

When I look at the application's error log, I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: Profile GL4bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x7fec7c6387a0, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x347988c, isOwner true, <6c54f992, c67a61e>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL4.hw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1795)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.initializeBackendImpl(GLJPanel.java:1377)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.paintComponent(GLJPanel.java:549)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.paintChildren(JSplitPane.java:1047)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Profile GL4bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x7fec7c6387a0, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x347988c, isOwner true, <6c54f992, c67a61e>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL4.hw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:991)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.verifyInstance(GLContextImpl.java:1471)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.setGLFunctionAvailability(GLContextImpl.java:1942)
    at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXContext.createImpl(X11GLXContext.java:395)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrentWithinLock(GLContextImpl.java:765)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:648)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:586)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1731)
    ... 46 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: Profile GL4bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x7fec7c6387a0, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x5968457d, isOwner true, <2bdd35ae, 7b0ee940>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL4.hw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1795)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.initializeBackendImpl(GLJPanel.java:1377)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.paintComponent(GLJPanel.java:549)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.paintChildren(JSplitPane.java:1047)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Profile GL4bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x7fec7c6387a0, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x5968457d, isOwner true, <2bdd35ae, 7b0ee940>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL4.hw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:991)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.verifyInstance(GLContextImpl.java:1471)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.setGLFunctionAvailability(GLContextImpl.java:1942)
    at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXContext.createImpl(X11GLXContext.java:395)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrentWithinLock(GLContextImpl.java:765)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:648)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:586)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1731)
    ... 46 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: Profile GL4bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x7fec7c6387a0, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x1051ac5f, isOwner true, <4ba86e02, 4c664ac8>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL4.hw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1795)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.initializeBackendImpl(GLJPanel.java:1377)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.paintComponent(GLJPanel.java:549)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.paintChildren(JSplitPane.java:1047)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Profile GL4bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x7fec7c6387a0, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x1051ac5f, isOwner true, <4ba86e02, 4c664ac8>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL4.hw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:991)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.verifyInstance(GLContextImpl.java:1471)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.setGLFunctionAvailability(GLContextImpl.java:1942)
    at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXContext.createImpl(X11GLXContext.java:395)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrentWithinLock(GLContextImpl.java:765)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:648)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:586)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1731)
    ... 46 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: Profile GL4bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x7fec7c6387a0, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x73880a23, isOwner true, <2c739bf2, 1d689b54>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL4.hw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1795)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.initializeBackendImpl(GLJPanel.java:1377)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.paintComponent(GLJPanel.java:549)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.paintChildren(JSplitPane.java:1047)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

... and on and on.

So, apparently the software is looking for the Profile GL4bc which is not available. The Java libraries are as required by the software (Oracle Java 8 ).

Web searches return similar problems with MatLab, SciLab and "SweetHomestead" (?) and generally, the advice is to set an environmental variable:

Code:

```
export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965
```

However, although I've tried doing this, it made no difference.

The glxgears test works fine for me, both using the override and the default 'iris' setting. As far as I have been able to tell to date, it is only this application that is affected.

Some info on my system follows:

```
$ inxi -Fxz

System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
  Desktop: MATE 1.24.0 Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: Z170M-PLUS v: Rev X.0x serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1805 date: 06/20/2016 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-6700K bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Skylake-S rev: 3 L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 63999 
  Speed: 2719 MHz min/max: 800/4200 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2800 2: 2800 
  3: 2800 4: 2800 5: 2800 6: 2800 7: 2800 8: 2800 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-42-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-V vendor: ASUSTeK driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k 
  port: f040 bus ID: 00:1f.6 
  IF: enp0s31f6 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 9.36 TiB used: 6.00 TiB (64.1%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVPV128HDGM-00000 
  size: 119.24 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST1000DX001-1NS162 size: 931.51 GiB 
  ID-3: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: Seagate model: Expansion size: 1.82 TiB 
  ID-4: /dev/sdc type: USB model: KESU USB 3.0 size: 149.05 GiB 
  ID-5: /dev/sdd type: USB vendor: Seagate model: Expansion size: 1.82 TiB 
  ID-6: /dev/sde type: USB vendor: Western Digital model: WD Elements 25A2 
  size: 1.82 TiB 
  ID-7: /dev/sdf type: USB vendor: Western Digital 
  model: WD My Passport 0827 size: 931.48 GiB 
  ID-8: /dev/sdg type: USB vendor: Western Digital model: WD Elements 25A2 
  size: 1.82 TiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 113.55 GiB used: 37.67 GiB (33.2%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p4 
  ID-2: /home size: 909.44 GiB used: 580.26 GiB (63.8%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/sda2 
  ID-3: swap-1 size: 7.45 GiB used: 122.8 MiB (1.6%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda1 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C mobo: 27.8 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 326 Uptime: 19h 32m Memory: 62.72 GiB used: 5.53 GiB (8.8%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 clang: 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
  Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38 


$ glxinfo|grep OpenGL :

OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:


$ lspci -k

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 530
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

So, in conclusion what are my options here?

Comment: any news on this ?